# Insert/transform to 0 or 1 based on presence of text

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'd like to insert to a table's bit column either 0 or 1, 0 where there is no text, 1 where there is. I am pulling data through an excel source in SSIS. In the example below, it should go:

```
Client 1: 1    1    1
Client 2: 1    0    1
```

How it looks in excel:

```
Products:   Ball    Bicycle     Bat 

Client 1:   Ball    Bicycle     Bat

Client 2:   Ball                Bat

Client 3:   Ball

Client 4:           Bicycle     Bat
```

Any way to achieve this in SSIS?

Comment: Is this part of a larger package? Doesn't seem necessary to use SSIS.

Comment: Yes, its part of a package pulling nearly 30 columns. I don't know of a way to accomplish this on a table's case statement, or a default constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a few items to accomplish this.

## How do I add new columns to a data flow task?

A Derived Column will allow you to create these new boolean columns. A derived column uses an Expression to compute a value. You'll need to specify the column name when you create a new one. You'll also want to ensure the data types are as expected.

### What's my expression?

The first is whether the no text comes in as NULL, an empty string or a padded string. Knowing whether the current row satisfies one of those conditions will tell us whether we need to make our new column 1 or 0.

A value is either NULL or NOT NULL. If it's not null, then we need to worry about whether it's empty/padded. We test for NULL via the `ISNULL` expression.

A boolean OR is expressed as `||`

An equality test is done via `==`

We check for an empty string using the `LEN` expression.

We need to remove all the trailing spaces from our column to see if it reduces down to an empty string. We'll use `RTRIM` to accomplish this.

An Expression must evaluate to something, but we have conditional (if) logic. The way we work around that is the ternary operator `(boolean test) ? (true expr) : (false expr)`

The SSIS system data type for boolean is `DT_BOOL`

A cast is performed by `(DT_TYPE) VALUE`

### Putting it all together

Add a derived column component to your data flow. Make the column name `Col1HasText`

Line breaks added for readability

```
(isnull([Col1]) || LEN(RTRIM([Col1])) == 0) ? 
((DT_BOOL) 0) :
((DT_BOOL) 1)
```

English version: If Col1 is null or if the length of the right-trimmed version of Col1 is zero, then we want to cast one to a data type of DT_BOOL (boolean). Otherwise, cast zero to a data type of DT_BOOL

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I seem to be getting formatting errors any way I input this expression:
(ISNULL([Column] || LEN(RTRIM([Column])) == 0) ? ((DT_BOOL) 1) :((DT_BOOL) 0)
Anything you know of that could hinder this coming from excel? There would be blank cells, cells with text.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed the closing parenthesis in the ISNULL call. It should have been `ISNULL([Col1]) ||...`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I wound up with the below, I just switched the 0 and 1, to place 0's for blanks, and 1's for cases wherever text is present:
(ISNULL(Col1) || LEN(RTRIM(Col1)) == 0) ? ((DT_BOOL)0) : ((DT_BOOL)1)